# Trajectories in phase space of a non autonomous Hamiltonian

Tags: dynamical-systems, hamilton-equations

If I have some autonomus hamiltonian, then it is a constant of the motion, and all the trajectories will lie on constant set levels.

For example, for the double well potential problem

$$H(x,p) = p^2-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{4}x^4$$

the equations of motion will be given by hamilton's equations

$$\frac{\partial H(x,p)}{\partial p} = \dot{x} = 2p$$
$$-\frac{\partial H(x,p)}{\partial x} = \dot{p} = x-x^3$$

and the solutions to these ODE's will be  trajectories that will lie on the curves

[image]

How will the equations of motion change when the hamiltonian turns non-autonomous?

$$H(x,p,t)=p^2-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{4}x^4+\epsilon t$$

will the trajectories lie on constant surface levels?